# Hide form details in browser

Tags: angularjs

Recently I'm making a registration form on my site but there are some attributes that people can "hack".
My form is in angular js (version 1) and there are a lot of attributes that everyone can "eliminate" simply by inspecting the code:

required;

minlength

....

how can I hide those elements? in angular every attribute is shown in browser's console; I remember in spring mvc you can't see them. I do not want to hide everything, just the most important attributes like required, min/maxlength, pattern.... what can I do?

Comment: just curious, What issue are you trying to solve by hiding the information? There may be another way of solving the issue that you have?

Comment: it's just a safety issue. recently I downloaded a file from a site simply removing required from a field(email). I don't want the users can do this on my site.

Comment: Ok, then you always repeat the validation of the input sent to the server on the  server to ensure the request is what you expect. Therefore it doesn't matter what changes you do client side to to the data. The server will do all the correct checks. Had that happened then your attempted download would have failed? Seriously, the server must do all the data validation to ensure the request is correct. Never trust any data from a client.

Comment: so I should do the validation both html and js side? nope, the download succeded.

Comment: Ok, just one thing I don't understand.. which part of my program would do the "server validation"? I'm using java and angularjs. I suppose when I'll finish the job I'll put my site on a personal domain bought on a hosting site.. Do I miss something?